# Cannot download googleservice-info.plist in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I added a Firebase project (iOS app). But I get following notice at the console of the project:

> There was an error. The config file cannot be downloaded at this time.

What is wrong?  Is it because the project is conflict with some other one existing in some other Firebase account (e.g., having the same `bundle id`)

Comment: have you check that your added .plist file are correct or not?

Comment: Did you tried like this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en

Comment: Ever solved this? Get the same error...